# Data in Firestore is one step behind what's in Vue3 project

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Firestore: Updating document seems to be behind by one action when updating multiple times

Hello all, I am using Firestore 9 in my Vue3 project with the following structure:

[image: Firestore db structure]

The data is shown in a table that allows users to edit field values with a popup editor. Once the popup editor is submitted, the updateDb function is called.

The updateDb function:

```
async function updateDb(
    json: Loan[] | CreditCard[] | Bill[] | Income[] | Payment[],
    name: string
  ) {
    if (currentUser.value === null) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('updateDb', currentUser.value?.uid, {
      [name]: json,
    });
    try {
      await updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', currentUser.value?.uid), {
        [name]: json,
      });
      console.log('set');
      logEvent(analytics, 'update', {
        user: currentUser.value,
        name: name,
        json: json,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error', e);
      logEvent(analytics, 'update', {
        user: currentUser.value,
        name: name,
        json: json,
        error: e,
      });
    }
  }
```

This is hard to explain in words but it seems like the Firestore db itself is one "event" behind what's going on. In other words, this is what happens:

1. Initial firestore income[0] has an "amount" value of 2602 (as in screenshot above).
2. User edits the amount value in the table to 1000.

   ```
   console.log('updateDb', currentUser.value?.uid, {
     [name]: json,
   });
   ```

   Outputs the correct value with the new amount of 1000.
   However, Firestore still shows the initial amount of 2602.
3. User edits the amount value again, this time to 1500.

   ```
   console.log('updateDb', currentUser.value?.uid, {
     [name]: json,
   });
   ```

Outputs the correct value with the new amount of 1500.
However, Firestore now shows the amount from step 2 which is 1000.

[image: GIF of what's happening]

Comment: What you're describing sounds like an issue with the console, not your code.  That's not something Stack Overflow is suited to solve for you.  If you have a problem with the console that's easy to repeat, you should contact [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) about that so they can look into it.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, I've contacted Firebase as per your suggestion and will update OP if/when they respond. I'm going to leave this up in case anyone else has come across anything similar before.